# basis of the projective space

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

I am reading a lecture about projective geometry. It is defined the basis of $\mathbb{P}\mathbb{R}^{2}$ as follows:
$$A_{1}=(0,1) ,A_{2}=(1,0),A_{3}=(1,1)$$
, but they are not independent. Could you please explain to me why they consider such a basis for projective space?

Comment: What do you call a basis in this context? The projective plane is not a vector space.

Comment: I know, but it is defined above basis for the projective space. As I said I don't understand what it means

Comment: If you do not know the definition of what you are trying to understand, no one will.

Comment: I don't know your definitions. $\mathbb{PR}^{2}$ should be a projective plane, so the underlying vectors should be in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Is it possible that your basis is supposed to be interpreted as the points $(1:0:1)$, $(1:1:0)$, $(1:1:1)$?

Comment: Please  page 6 of http://morpheo.inrialpes.fr/people/Boyer/Teaching/M2R/geoProj.pdf

Comment: Just read carefully. Page 5 : there is a definition of a **projective basis**. Before that, there is a definition of an independant familly. Everything is written in your link.